# Are highly nitrated cyclopentadiene compounds possible?

Tags: synthesis, explosives, nitro-compounds

Has anybody synthesized di- or higher nitrated cyclopentadienes possibly with methyl or other groups in the 1 position (analogs of TNT)?

Answer (score 4):

Mono-nitrated cyclopentadienes and their benzo-analogues (indene, fluorene) have been prepared in the context of studies on *nitro-aci*-tautomerism.

As far as higher substitution is concerned, there seems to be at least a crystal structure of [potassium dinitrotrichlorocyclopentadienide](http://dx.doi.org/10.1107/S0567740872004637) reported in *Acta Cryst., B*

In the abstract, the authors (Y. Otaka, F. Marumo, and Y. Saito) mention the preparation of this compound by **Haga** in 1969, (sorry, reference is behind paywall) via

> nitration of hexachlorocyclopentadiene with alkali nitrite in an aqueous or ethanolic solution

NOTE: Hexachlorocyclopentadiene once was a favoured starting material in the synthesis of insecticides via Diels-Alder reaction. However, it is a **potent teratogen** and the "mother" of least five members of the **dirty dozen** (persistent organic pollutants) nowadays banned for good reason.

You might want to read the MSDS and then decide that you'd rather prefer to work with something else.

Comment: Thank you K.W. for the references.  No need by me for MSDS ;-) - not in the biz -- just a curiosity of mine in analogy to TNT!  I am sure that even if the more highly substituted CPD compounds could be made they would be horrendously explosive; maybe as stable as nitroglycerine itself!  Thanks again!  No reply needed.